# Organizar correctamente los legends de la gráfica - Google charts API

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-chart-api

Utilizo la API de Google Charts para crear esta gráfica:

*Gráfica #1:*

[image: Gráfica a modificar]

Pero tengo un problema: *el orden de los `legend` no es correcto*.

De acuerdo al código, he establecido este orden:

1. Cargado
2. No Cargado
3. Presupuesto

Pero, a pesar hacer varias pruebas, no logro ordenar los `legends` como se necesita; además, los colores que tiene la gráfica son los requeridos.

El resultado esperado debe ser así:

*Gráfica #2:*

[image: Resultado a obtener]

**¿Cómo puedo modificar el código de la gráfica para obtener el resultado esperado?**

> NOTA: La gráfica #2 fue realizada con DevExpress `dxChart`, pero,
>   debido a cambios de requerimiento y compatibilidad de navegadores, se optó por usar Google Charts API.

---

Aquí está el código completo de la gráfica #1 - *usando Google Charts API*:

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {
  packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  /*var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['SERIES', 'Cargado', 'No cargado', 'Presupuesto'],
    ['Afiliaciones', 100, 9, null],
    ['Presupuesto', null, null, 417]
     ]);*/

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'SERIES');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Cargado');
  data.addColumn('number', 'No Cargado');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Presupuesto');
  data.addRows([
    ['Afiliaciones', 100, 9, 0],
    ['Presupuesto', 0, 0, 417]
  ]);

  // Set chart options
  var options = {
    isStacked: true,
  };

  var options = {
    legend: {
      position: 'right'
    },
    chartArea: {
      right: 180, // set this to adjust the legend width
      left: 60, // set this to adjust the left margin
    },
    isStacked: true,
    colors: [
      '#FFA726',
      '#EF5350',
      '#6582ba'
    ]
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 706px; height: 311px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desafortunadamente los `legends` de la gráfica no pueden ser ordenados, ya que *(según la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options))*, cuando se aplica la propiedad `isStacked: true`, los `legends` son invertidos para corresponder mejor con las series.

Cito:

> If set to true, stacks the elements for all series at each domain
>   value. Note: In Column, Area, and SteppedArea charts, Google Charts
>   **reverses the order of legend items to better correspond with the
>   stacking of the series elements** (E.g. series 0 will be the bottom-most
>   legend item). This does not apply to Bar Charts.

Una solución *parcial* según esta [fuente](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/301) es:

> Cambiar el valor de `vAxis.direction` to `-1`, así las columnas
>   apiladas estarán en un orden opuesto a los ítems de las leyendas,
>   luego revertir el orden de sus categorías.

Sin embargo, el cambio no parece afectar el orden de los `legends`.

En definitiva, no encontré mejor solución que establecer solamente los colores de las series/columnas según lo solicitado y el orden de los `legends` es aceptable para el cumplimiento del requerimiento.